# Using FFMPEG library in PPAPI: Naclports with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, google-nativeclient, rtsp-client

I have configured Webports, ffmpeg; and I have created the following Makefile for the current project. However, I have met some problem with ffmpeg library linking.

```
$ TOOLCHAIN=pnacl make
  LINK pnacl/Release/client_unstripped.bc
pnacl/Release/src/client.o: error: undefined reference to 'av_register_all'
make: *** [pnacl/Release/client_unstripped.bc] Error 1
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here, my Makefile is shown below:

> VALID_TOOLCHAINS := pnacl glibc clang-newlib win
>
> NACL_SDK_ROOT ?= $(abspath $(CURDIR)/../..)
>
> TARGET = client
>
> OTHERDIR=src
>
> INC_DIR = inc
>
> FFMPEG_INC_DIR = ../../toolchain/mac_pnacl/le32-nacl/usr/include
>
> INCLUDES = -I$(INC_DIR) -I$(FFMPEG_INC_DIR)
>
> include $(NACL_SDK_ROOT)/tools/common.mk
>
> CHROME_ARGS += --allow-nacl-socket-api=localhost
>
> LIBS = nacl_io ppapi_cpp ppapi
>
> CFLAGS = -Wall -g -O2 $(INCLUDES)
>   -L../../toolchain/mac_pnacl/le32-nacl/usr/lib -lavformat \
>   -lvpx -lvorbisenc -lvorbis -logg -ltheoraenc -ltheoradec -logg -lmp3lame -lm -pthread -lavcodec -lvpx -lvorbisenc -lvorbis -logg \
>   -ltheoraenc -ltheoradec -logg -lmp3lame -lm -pthread -lswresample -lm -lavutil -lm -lavdevice -lavfilter
>
> SOURCES = $(OTHERDIR)/tcp_util.cc $(OTHERDIR)/tpool.cc
>   $(OTHERDIR)/net.cc $(OTHERDIR)/rtsp_response.cc \ $(OTHERDIR)/rtsp.cc
>   $(OTHERDIR)/rtsp_common.cc \ $(OTHERDIR)/rtsp_client.cc
>   $(OTHERDIR)/udp_util.cc \ $(OTHERDIR)/client.cc
>
> # Build rules generated by macros from common.mk:
>
> $(foreach src,$(SOURCES),$(eval $(call
>   COMPILE_RULE,$(src),$(CFLAGS))))
>
> # The PNaCl workflow uses both an unstripped and finalized/stripped binary.
>   # On NaCl, only produce a stripped binary for Release configs (not Debug). ifneq (,$(or $(findstring pnacl,$(TOOLCHAIN)),$(findstring
>   Release,$(CONFIG)))) $(eval $(call
>   LINK_RULE,$(TARGET)_unstripped,$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS))) $(eval
>   $(call STRIP_RULE,$(TARGET),$(TARGET)_unstripped)) else $(eval $(call
>   LINK_RULE,$(TARGET),$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS))) endif
>
> $(eval $(call NMF_RULE,$(TARGET),))

And here is the way, how the library has been used in the class context.

```
class VideoDecodePack {
public:
    VideoDecodePack() {
        av_register_all();
    }
};

class ClientInstance : public pp::Instance {
 public:
  explicit ClientInstance(PP_Instance instance) : pp::Instance(instance){
    cses = InitRtspClientSession();
    _videoDecoder = new VideoDecodePack();
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by adding linking with additional libraries for FFMPEG: vpx, vorbis, lame. And it is very important to keep the order of linked libraries.

```
.....
...
TARGET = client
INC_DIR := inc

include $(NACL_SDK_ROOT)/tools/common.mk

DEPS = ppapi_simple nacl_io
LIBS = ppapi_simple nacl_io ppapi pthread \
avformat vpx vorbisenc vorbis ogg theoraenc \
theoradec mp3lame m avcodec swresample avutil \
avdevice avfilter

OTHERDIR = src

CFLAGS = -Wall
# -I$(INC_DIR)
SOURCES = $(OTHERDIR)/client.cc

# Build rules generated by macros from common.mk:

$(foreach dep,$(DEPS),$(eval $(call DEPEND_RULE,$(dep))))
$(foreach src,$(SOURCES),$(eval $(call COMPILE_RULE,$(src),$(CFLAGS))))
....
...
```